# Is Flask current_app.config [thread/process safe]/editable?

Tags: python, flask

For example I have flask app with some config variable:

```
#__init__.py
app.config.from_mapping(
    ...
    WITH_INFO_MODULE = True,
    ...
```

and view file:

```
#view.py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("example.html")
```

and template:

```
#example.html
...
{% if config["WITH_INFO_MODULE"] %}
    <p> Info module included! </p>
{% endif %}
...
```

And *interesting* function:

```
from flask import current_app
...
@app.route("/change_settings", methods=["POST"])
def change_settings():
    current_app.config["WITH_INFO_MODULE"] = not current_app.config["WITH_INFO_MODULE"]
    return "OK"
```

Is Flask app.config[] thread safe? Is it good idea to change config variables in running application? If No: How I can solve such problem?